# ZURB Foundation for Apps [$injector:modulerr] error when adding modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation

I am working on a project with specific authentification that is already working in Ionic. I have to implement the same for the admin panel that will be available only for web devices, so I already installed all the dependencies, configured the app and did already the HTML/CSS stuff in ZURB Foundation for Apps 1.1. 
Now I am stuck on the implementation of the controllers and services.

I read the official documentation and there is not much explanation for the custom controllers and services, so I found few texts on the web that explain the structure of the Foundation for Apps. I found also a sample app with the structure that is explained here: [ORGANIZING ANGULAR FILES IN ZURB FOUNDATION FOR APPS](http://creativitykills.co/organizing-angular-files-in-zurb-foundation-for-apps/) and copied the sample files for each page from here: [Foundation for Apps Template](https://github.com/CreativityKills/foundation-apps-template)

So I put inside my app the **About, Contact, Home and Shared** folders inside the **assets/js** folder.

So the Shared folder for example contains **controllers.js** file with the following code:

```
   (function () {
    'use strict';
    var controllers;

    AppCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function AppCtrl($scope) {
        // This is a shared controller because its the application parent controller
    }

    controllers = {
        AppCtrl: AppCtrl
    };

    angular.module('SharedModule').controller(controllers);
})
```

The **module.js** file contains this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
  angular.module('SharedModule', [ /* Dependencies to be shared everywhere */ ]);
})
```

The **app.js** file has the almost the same code as the generated file, except the custom modules are specified:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('application', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate',

    //foundation
    'foundation',
    'foundation.dynamicRouting',
    'foundation.dynamicRouting.animations',

    // My modules
    'SharedModule',
    'ContactModule',
    'AboutModule',
    'HomeModule'
  ])
    .config(config)
    .run(run)
  ;

  config.$inject = ['$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'];

  function config($urlProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlProvider.otherwise('/');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled:false,
      requireBase: false
    });

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
  }

  function run() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
  }

})();
```

So now, when I run the application I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   application due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate
>   module HomeModule due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'HomeModule'
>   is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to
>   load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the
>   dependencies as the second argument.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.

I tried to remove the modules one by one to test if there is a problem with individual modules, but the same error was thrown, so I checked the individual files as well, but the files look the same as in the sample app. Then, I checked if the dependencies are called, but since they are not called inside the index file like in a regular AngularJS app, I compared the gulpfile.js and came with the solution:
Inside the appJS array I had to include the paths for the .js files, so that part of the gulpfile.js looks like this now:

```
  appJS: [
    'client/assets/js/app.js',

    // Load my modules
    'client/assets/js/*/module.js',
    'client/assets/js/*/controllers.js',
    'client/assets/js/*/factories.js',
    'client/assets/js/*/services.js',
    'client/assets/js/*/directives.js'
  ]
```